# SQL "Conditional" where clause

Tags: sql

I have a table that I'm populating via a queue and I am unable to alter the structure of the table.

Issue:
The table contains four identifiers - SKU, Department, Class, and Subclass - and I need to return other fields from the table in order of the first condition met below:

1. if the SKU exists in the table then get the values for the sku
2. else if the Department/Class/Subclass of the SKU exists in the table get
   values
3. else if the Department/Class of the SKU exists in the table
   get values
4. else if the Department of the SKU exists in the table get
   values.
5. else there are no applicable values for the SKU (I don't
   think this happens)

I'm populating report fields in a java application from this table and I don't want to write four queries to check each of these cases. I don't believe I'm able to do any procedural SQL so I need to do this via a native sql query.

Any help is appreciated.

I had to alter the query a bit.  The query below works:

```
 Select dept, class, subclass,
       case
         when sku = :sku then 1
         when dept = :dept and class = :class and subclass = :subclass then 2
         when dept = :dept and class = :class then 3
         when dept = :dept then 4
       end as priority,
       field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
From   schema.table
where  sku = :sku
       or (dept = :dept and class = :class and subclass = :class)
       or (dept = :dept and class = :class and subclass is null)
       or (dept = :dept and class is null and subclass is null)
order by priority asc
```

;

Comment: I'm missing something.  Are you populating the table or are you querying it? Sample data and desired results can really help explain what you want to do.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you pass 4 parameeters (SKU, Department, Class, and Subclass) in the query and need value fields for the parameters.

```
select
    case
      when sku=:sku then 1
      when Department=:Department and Class=:Class and Subclass=:Subclass then 2
      when Department=:Department and Class=:Class then 3
      when Department=:Department then 4
   end as priority,
   <value field here>
from the_table t
where sku=:sku
   or Department=:Department
   or Class=:Class
   or Subclass=:Subclass
order by priority
```

The first line of the query is what you need. How to extract the first line depends on DB you use

Comment: Thanks.  Just what I'm looking for.  I did not think about returning a priority in the resulting fields.